# Incoming text messages iOS5 cannot be detected by app

Tags: iphone, text, message, nsnotificationcenter

My app (using `AVMoviePlayer`) crashes when an incoming text message is received, as well as a local notification from another app. These messages usually appear in that thin notification center at the top of the screen.

The trouble is, `ApplicationWillResignActive` does NOT get called when one of these message appears.  I set an alarm (iPhone app clock), and THAT does make an `ApplicationWillResignActive` message appear. I can respond properly as long as I get a message, but the texts and local notifications don't seem to be detected.

Is there a message I can add an observer for that will tell me when a `notificationcenter` notification has come in?  I mean notification in the sense of that little thin bar at the top of the screen, rather than `NSNotificationCenter`.

Comment: Why does the app crash when notification centre pops up the text message / local notification? What actually crashes? It's likely a sound will be played so you will probably get an audio session interruption which you might be able to use to detect this state.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with AVMoviePlayer,but in the case of other players you can handle the cases in either player interruption delegate methods or session interruption delegate methods.